# How to get to the Blue Lagoon from Reykjavik cheaply?

Tags: budget, iceland, reykjavik

What is the way to get from Reykjavik to the Blue Lagoon for the cheapest price?

Comment: Are you also going to or from the airport? The cheapest option is to take transport between the airport and stop at the lagoon.

Comment: You have tagged your question [tag:iceland], [tag:reyjavik], and [tag:budget].  The latter is mutually exclusive with either of the first two.  Your best bet is to bring a bicycle.

Comment: Though I think I would enjoy having a bike, it would be far too difficult to bring in my carry-on :P I'll look at renting bikes though, good idea!

Comment: @gerrit After having gone and come back, I realize only now that you were joking and I was an idiot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no local bus service to the Blue Lagoon so your formal options are essentially walk (the whole way could take days), hire a car or take a taxi. Assuming a ~70 km trek does not suit, there are unofficial alternatives that might suit.

There is a [bus](https://www.re.is/flybus) that runs between Reykjavik and the international airport at Keflavik. Cost for a singe (adult) is around 2.500 ISK (about $20). It does stop between termini but not where would suit you, so you would have to persuade the driver to be helpful. That might not be possible if a bus is running late, since it has flights to catch, but the service is roughly hourly and if the first won't co-operate, the second might. (The schedule is too frequent to be covered by the same driver on consecutive journeys.)

If to drop you off at the 43/41 junction just after Vogar you would be left with a walk of about five miles. However the second part of 'unofficial' is that Icelanders are very helpful to hitchhikers and, depending upon the time of day, there is a good chance of a lift for at least part of the way.

Comment: Also please note that you would need to arrange to get somewhere **from** Blue Lagoon. It is literally in the middle of nowhere (basically a huge stoned lava field), there is NOTHING nearby.

Comment: That's what worried me, that's a really crappy place to be strangled in.

Comment: @GeorgeY. And I hope that by "strangled" you mean "stranded"!

Comment: Also grayline.is buses were couple dollars cheaper than Flybus last Aug when I was there.

Comment: Not sure about this, there are two different buses at the airport, grayline had their own with their livery, but I think flybus is too. Maybe because Euro is down comparing to Aug?

Comment: I think I'm past the point of being able to edit my question to include a return journey, but I'll need that too!

Answer (score 2):

The cheapest option I'm aware of (short of hitchhiking) would be the buses operated by [Reykjavik Excursions](https://www.re.is/day-tours/blue-lagoon). You can buy a round trip ticket that includes admission to the lagoon for 9600 ISK.

[Grayline](http://grayline.is/tours/blue-lagoon/) also offers this service for 86 EUR (approx 10600 ISK).

In case you have a rental car, the admission alone is 5400 ISK. Do keep in mind that [pre-booking is required](http://www.bluelagoon.com/blue-lagoon-spa/prices-and-packages/).